# Windows 10 21H2 - How to prevent the start menu sidebar from expanding on hover?

Tags: windows-10-v21h1

I'm looking for a way to permanently disable the Windows 10 start menu sidebar from expanding automatically on hover, or disable the expanding "feature" altogether, ideally without a third party program, but through modifying the OS files or registry, on the most recent version of Windows 10.

Comment: 'Classic Start' is a useful application to give you a useable start menu similar to that of windows 7, removing the current start menu but leaving it accessible if needed.

Comment: Your not going to get the behavior you want without a program like Classic Start, Start10, or StartIsBack++